# Safari no me carga todas las webfonts personalizadas, ¿alguna opción?

Tags: html, css, web

Tengo un problema con la carga de webfonts. Y es que, en todos los demás navegadores de dispositivos como Android todas las webfonts se cargan perfectamente. Sin embargo, cuando intento cargar la página web usando Safari, no todas las webfonts configuradas se me cargan, mostrando unas fonts que nada que ver con el diseño original.

Les comparto screenshots de la página web. Una cargada usando el navegador Vivaldi en Android y la otra usando Safari en iOS.

[image: Página web cargada con Vivaldi en Android 11.]

[image: La misma página web pero caragada usando Safari en iOS 16.3]

He aquí mi código CSS:

```css
/* Minion Pro Family Font */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.svg#MinionPro-Regular') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-Semibold';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.svg#MinionPro-Semibold') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-SemiboldIt';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldIt.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldIt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldIt.svg#MinionPro-SemiboldIt') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldIt.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldIt.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldIt.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-Bold';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Bold.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Bold.svg#MinionPro-Bold') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-BoldCn';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCn.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCn.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCn.svg#MinionPro-BoldCn') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCn.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCn.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCn.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-BoldCnIt';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCnIt.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCnIt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCnIt.svg#MinionPro-BoldCnIt') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCnIt.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCnIt.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldCnIt.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-BoldIt';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldIt.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldIt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldIt.svg#MinionPro-BoldIt') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldIt.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldIt.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-BoldIt.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-It';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-It.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-It.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-It.svg#MinionPro-It') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-It.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-It.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-It.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-Medium';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Medium.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Medium.svg#MinionPro-Medium') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Medium.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-MediumIt';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-MediumIt.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-MediumIt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-MediumIt.svg#MinionPro-MediumIt') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-MediumIt.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-MediumIt.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-MediumIt.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionPro-Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.svg#MinionPro-Regular') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/MinionPro-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Pese a ponerle el atributo a font-display como 'swap', éste al momento de cargarlo en el navegador de iOS simplemente no se carga y me muestra la letra tipo 'Times New Roman' toda fea, y que nada tiene que ver con la font que quiero mostrar. Por lo que me gustaría saber en dónde estoy fallando y qué hacer ahora para que Safari me muestra la webfont de manera correcta.

Sin más por el momento, eso es todo. Un gran saludo a todos y buen día.

Comment: Cómo estás usando ese CSS?

Comment: ¿Tienes una versión en línea de la página para poder probar qué está ocurriendo? No tengo un iPhone con iOS, pero sí un MacBook con macOS Monterey.

Comment: https://www.harmonycreativa.net/Repertorio/HistoriasCortas/JazminyRoger.php 

Actualmente tengo la página en línea, y no había notado ese detalle con el font-face hasta que empecé a visitar la web en navegador Safari bajo ecosistema iOS y noto el problema con la carga de la fuente